# Button elements inside the table is shown above the text in div element

Tags: css, html-table, sticky

I have created a sticky header for filtering the data inside the html table using jquery. The problem I am encountering is with the alignment of the sticky element and the elements in the table.

I have tried with z-index but it didnt help. And also changing the margin attribute applies the margin to the sticky element also.

```
<style>
body,th,td
{
    font-family: serif;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
}
table
{
width: 125%;
overflow: auto;
margin: 50px auto;
}
caption
{
text-align: center;
margin: 10px auto;
font-family: serif;
font-size: 28px;
font-style: italic;
}
th,td
{
background-color: white;
border: 2px solid black;
height: 50px;
}
button
{
margin-left: 2px;
margin-right: 2px;
}
#srch_bar
{
position: -webkit-sticky;
top: 5px;
position: sticky;
margin-top: 10px;
float: right;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: white;
}
#srch_bar select
{
outline: none;
border: none;
padding: none;
}
#LSRCH
{
text-transform: uppercase;
}
</style>
<script>//only the needed part is added
            for(j=0; j<res_stock.length; j++)
        {
            var trow    =   '<tr>';
            trow        +=  '<td>'  +   res_stock[j].slno   +   '</td>';
            trow        +=  '<td>'  +   res_stock[j].lotNo  +   '</td>';
            trow        +=  '<td>'  +   res_stock[j].parName    +   '</td>';
            trow        +=  '<td><button class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward btn-success btn-sm" id="UPD'    +   res_stock[j].slno   +   '"></button><button class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit btn-warning btn-sm" id="EDT'    +   res_stock[j].slno   +   '"></button><button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-danger btn-sm" id="DEL'    +   res_stock[j].slno   +   '"></button></td>';
            trow        +=  '<td>'  +   res_stock[j].gMtr   +   '</td>';
            trow        +=  '<td>'  +   res_stock[j].gWt    +   '</td>';
            trow        +=  '<td>'  +   res_stock[j].gActWt +   '</td>';
            trow        +=  '<td>'  +   res_stock[j].gRPWaWf    +   '</td>';
            trow        +=  '<td>'  +   res_stock[j].gGF.substring(res_stock[j].gGF.indexOf('G')+1,res_stock[j].gGF.indexOf('F'))   +   '</td>';
            trow        +=  '<td>'  +   tone_stretcher(res_stock[j].tone)   +   '</td>';
            trow        +=  '</tr>';
            $(trow).appendTo('#stk_tbl');
        }
```

the table is generated by dynamic data from json file using jquery. The problem is I have three buttons inside the table for options related to that particular row. When I scroll across the table, the buttons are shown above the sticky element. Instead it should go behind the sticky element.

Comment: Maybe because the `float: right`? Also for margin issue, you need to use `padding-top: 1px` on the container.

Comment: But other elements of the table go behind the sticky element. Only buttons have this problem